# Text widget to fill half of screen

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have a `python tkinter` program and i have two text widgets that need to be side by side. How can i get the two widgets to take up exactly half of the window which is 400 x 400 px ?

My Code is here

```
import tkinter

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.title("App")
        self.root.geometry("400x400")
        self.root.update()
        self.box1Text = tkinter.Text(self.root)
        self.box1Text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH,side=tkinter.LEFT)
        self.box2Text = tkinter.Text(self.root)
        self.box2Text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH,side=tkinter.RIGHT)

App = MyApp()
```

Comment: use `fill=BOTH`. And show us your code, please

Comment: i have tried `fill=BOTH` and `expand=1` but one takes up more than the other @ForceBru

Comment: `import tkinter

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):
    self.root = tkinter.Tk()
self.root.title("App")self.root.geometry("400x400")
self.root.update()

  self.box1Text = tkinter.Text(self.root)
         self.box1Text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH,side=tkinter.LEFT)
        
         self.box2Text = tkinter.Text(self.root)
         self.box2Text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH,side=tkinter.RIGHT)`

Comment: Please, put it into your question and format correctly.

Comment: i cannot tab for some reason

Comment: no-one can tab: use 4 spaces instead

Comment: Too bad code formatting, please indent it correctly

Comment: what is so bad about my code

Comment: please read any Markdown tutorial about code formatting. It can be formatted not only using `'s, but with four spaces too

Comment: Please answer the question or find something better to do than insult my lack of English skills

Comment: I've never insulted you, just gave you some piece of advice on how to format your code better.

Comment: But do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: You can add `width=200, height=400` to each initializer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the text widget wants to be 80 characters wide by 24 characters tall. If you don't specify a size, tkinter will do its best to make sure the widget is that size. If it can't fit all the widgets at their requested size it will start shrinking widgets, starting with the last widget created. That is why the first widget takes up all (or most) of the window -- tkinter tries to display it, and then will give any left-over room to the next widget.  In this case there is zero left over room.

Since you are giving the window an explicit size, you can give the text widget a width and height of 1 (one), and then let the geometry manager expand the widget to fill the extra space. You also need to tell pack to let the widget expand. So, add `width=1, height=1` to the definition of the widgets, and then add `expand=True` when packing the widgets in the frame.

Here is a working example:

```
import tkinter

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.title("App")
        self.root.geometry("400x400")
        self.root.update()
        self.box1Text = tkinter.Text(self.root, width=1, height=1)
        self.box1Text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH,side=tkinter.LEFT, expand=True)
        self.box2Text = tkinter.Text(self.root, width=1, height=1)
        self.box2Text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH,side=tkinter.RIGHT, expand=True)

App = MyApp()
App.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would I set it to fill the whole screen, while still allowing for a scrollbar?